# Finding a string in a string via regex in Go

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to write a regex that returns a string to me

I have a full string like this:

```
@badges=moderator/1,premium/1;color=#00FF80;display-name=gempir;emotes=;id=d0358df2-f0a1-4600-910e-515ec52b1baa;mod=1;room-id=99659894;sent-ts=1489250823035;subscriber=0;tmi-sent-ts=1489250823211;turbo=0;user-id=77829817;user-type=mod :gempir!gempir@gempir.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #gempbot :!status
```

and what to find the command "PRIVMSG" because there are similar full strings that have different commands. Like this:

```
@ban-duration=20;ban-reason=Banned\slink;room-id=11148817;target-user-id=78424343 :tmi.twitch.tv CLEARCHAT
```

If you are interested these are twitch irc messages with ircv3 tags

now I have this regex:

```
^@(.*)\s:(.*?)tmi.twitch.tv\s
```

how do I use the regex or a similar one in Go to find the string im looking for?

I wanted to avoid splitting again and again because it seems kinda unreasonable and hard to read. I think a regex can fix all my problems.

Comment: What stops you from using the same pattern in Go?

Comment: Go has a regexp package:  https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/

Comment: well regex.Match would return the whole beginning of the string etc. I wasnt sure how to use the regex correctly

Comment: Probably you should use FindAllMatch or FindAllSubmatch then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following *regex* should do it ...

```
(?<=twitch.tv\s)\w+(?=\s#)
```

see **[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oNSKfj/2)**

Comment: Go regex does not support any lookarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Just not to be anchored to the web-address (which can be changed some time) i'd prefer this kind:

```
([A-Z]+)(\s#.+)?$
```